# Foundation: sticky side menu

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a layout, with a sticky header bar and a sticky right menu which sits directly below the header bar and to the left of the content area. Below is my attempt - which causes the side accordion menu (placeholder) to appear in the incorrect position.

I have just used the default CSS etc from a fresh install of foundation for sites (6.5.3).

Why is my menu (placeholder) not staying in position when I scroll?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBKaLq

```
    <div data-sticky-container id="header">
        <div class="top-bar" data-sticky data-margin-top="0">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <h3>Cool page title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">John Doe <a href="">Logout</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-x">

        <div class="cell medium-3 show-for-medium" data-sticky-container>
            <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-top-anchor="header:bottom">
                <h3>Menu placeholder</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell medium-9">
            <h1>
                Start content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
                content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
            </h1>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: what you want the menu to be when scrolled?

Comment: on large screen the menu will be short enough to never scroll. on medium and small screens the menu may need to scroll independently. I've edited to mention that i intend to use the accordion menu. thx

Comment: Further testing reveals that this is a problem with having a sticky component anchoring to another sticky component. ie if I remove the sticky-ness from the header, the menu placeholder sticks nicely - although my header disappears which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchoring two sticky components, one to the other would be a challenge. Instead, you can use the example from the Foundation docs, which is very similar.

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/

The topnav is regular position fixed and the body is padded down to make space for the nav.

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Here is your example that way: https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/BbyRav

Comment: thanks rafi, btw i have an open issue regarding the same, feel free to handle as you think is appropriate https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/11699